# Button "Click" issue with Rails/Capybara/Webkit (tests pass in Selenium)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, selenium, webkit, capybara

I'm working on a Rails App and we've started using capybara for our functional tests. Our tech lead has had us writing tests and using Selenium, but then wants to switch to webkit for final testing prior to a deploy.

I've written a set of functional tests that mimic a user clicking through a tree menu, clicking a button to open a modal, clicking a few buttons within the modal (eventually opening a form), and then submitting the button.

These tests pass with flying colors in selenium. Firefox pops open and it whips through the complete test suite.

Switch over to webkit, and there is a consistent point at which the tests fail. When the modal is open, and it attempts to "click" a button to switch from a "Interaction History Form" to a "New Interaction Form"

The following is a list of the various command attempts I've done at "clicking" the New Interaction Button.

With selenium, this is simple and works:

click_button('New Interaction')

and some of these work in selenium, some don't, but none of them work with WebKit.

# page.execute_script %Q{ $('.btn.btn-default.toggle-interaction').css('display, inline-block'); }

# page.execute_script %Q{ $('.fa.fa-plus').click(); }

# page.find('.btn.btn-default.toggle-interaction').click

# within('#interaction-history') { find_button('New Interaction').click }

click_button('New Interaction')

# find_button('New Interaction').trigger('click')

# within(".btn.toggle-interaction") do

#   click_on("New Interaction")

# end

# find('.btn.toggle-interaction').trigger('click')

# find_button('New Interaction').click

# within('.insight-wrapper') { find_button('New Interaction').click }

We decided to try and use the capybara-screenshot gem, so that we could get a snapshot of the HTML and the "rendered" page during headless test failure.

I don't have a good photo editing app so I can't scrub out the protected info to post a screenshot, but in the saved snapshots (and saved html files), the images look right.

One idiosyncrasy in the screenshots is the location of the mouse cursor in the screenshot. Sometimes it's on the button it attempted to click, and other's it isn't.

One other idea we entertained is the idea that it could be a timing issue, and that it's trying to click the button before it has been successfully rendered. To mitigate that we added a pause method that forced the tests to wait. That didn't resolve the issue.

We looked at switching to a headless selenium using poltergeist/phantomJS, but a lot of the comments on that route seem to indicate a higher quantity of "random JS errors" than with webkit. Would there be an alternative headless selenium solution that could be worth investigating?

Thank you for your time and help,
Alex

Comment: Can you please edit and use the proper code formatting? You just select a block of text and press CTL + K (or CMD + k)? Also note that vs questions or questions asking for a tool, gem, book etc are not apprechiated on StackoverFlow. http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: What errors exactly do you get?